# netcat doesn't transfer complete file when using UDP

Tags: linux, netcat

I use the following in order to transfer bigfile (11GB):

```
cat bigfile | pv -L 11m | nc -u 10.0.0.1 3333
```

After 1.6GB the client **stop** to transfer (in the target machine i dont see packets )

**This is not lost packet problem, because the PV is on the cat in the client side.**

Both computer running Ubuntu.
For the first 1.6GB i see in wireshark on the target machine that it get the packets, but after 1.6GB the PV on the client side dosnt show any progress and wireshark on target machine show that no packets arrived.
If i CTRL-C the sender and start it again i see that packets arrived, so i dont think it server problem (netcat run on the server like this  - nc -u -l 10.0.0.10 3333 > bigfile).

Any idea why?

Comment: This is by design: UDP does not guarantee delivery of packets. You may lose parts of your file, some parts might be duplicated, and other may be reodered. If you don't want this, don't use UDP.

Comment: The PV is on the cat. the client stop send packets after 1.6GB

Comment: Which OS? Network layout (both computers on same subnet)? How did you check that no packets arrive at the target - with a sniffer? Do you see the packets for the first 1.6GB?

Comment: @YanivAknin i added this data to the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, try `dd if=file bs=1M | pv -L 11m | nc -u 10.0.0.1 3333` instead. I wonder if it's something to do with how much data cat is putting into the pipe?